# How to run visual studio build in azure devops

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

[image]I want to build my solution file in azure devops. I have added this to build pipeline, I see this step doesn't succeed. It tells " MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified." I suspect I am making some mistake in specifyning 
**msbuild args**

```
msbuild $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\ansysfnonet\ansysfnonet.vs2017.sln /t:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\ansysfnonet\ansysfnonet.csproj:Rebuild;

I tried specify only proj file as msbuild arg it didn't work for me
```

I tried without specifying msbuild it throws me whole lot of errors.

Someone please help me , why I am failing in this step and how to solve this error.

Thanks[image]

Comment: For `.net core` project, we often recommend to use `dotnet restore` instead of using `nuget restore` in Azure Devops. You can convert your solution into an answer then accept it, thus other SO users could refer to that solution:-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify an `msbuild` command line in the *MSBuild Arguments* field. You need to specify **any additional** MSBuild parameters beyond the defaults.

Clear that field. That should fix the problem you're encountering.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I removed th msbuild args when I run the build

Comment: ansysfnonet\FNOServices.cs(22,17): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

ansysfnonet\FNOServices.cs(165,28): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IOptions<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Note : Visual studio adds some folders like debug, .vs, then this error seems to disappear, I am not sure what these folders

Comment: I am new to visual studio, I guess it imports some library

Comment: You need to do a nuget restore before you build.

Comment: I added nuget restore before I start visual studio builder in the pipeline, 
The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Errors in C:\agent1\_work\1\s\ansysfnonet\ansysfnonet.csproj
    Package Microsoft.Extensions.Options 2.1.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Options 2.1.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0.)

Packages failed to restore

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you so much instead of nuget restore I used dotnet restore that made the build sucessful